# Dynamic origin of the graph data

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a table in Excel with sales of sellers on weekdays.

What I wanted to do was make a line chart, but only with the selected seller type this:

[image]

How do I put the chart only display the data of the seller selected?

File: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22618054/grafico_dinamico.xlsx

PS: the cell D8 is a dropdown select list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a chart based on a line of data that you fill in later, not directly off the table.

*Assuming table starts in A1*
Set up the data line as:

```
=Seller
=offset($A$1,match(Seller,$A:$A,0)-1,1)
=offset($A$1,match(Seller,$A:$A,0)-1,2)
...
```

we subtract 1 from the match, as match gives us a number starting with 1, and offset uses a number starting at 0.  If your table starts at another cell, subtract that row number to get the correct position for the data line to read (e.g. if table is at **$Q$77**, then the `match` formula would be `match(Seller,$Q:$Q,0)-77`.

Comment: thx for your replay. hi have try put the ```=Seller``` and the ```=offset($A$1,match(Seller,$A:$A,0)-1,1)``` in 'Legend Series', but I got a error.

Comment: create a line of data, the 1st cell refers to the **Seller** cell, and the following cells refer to the data (so, somewhere around A1000:G1000 you have what looks like a duplicate of the appropriate line of the table.  Use this as your data points in your graph, not the original table

Answer (score 0):

Create a "Pivot Chart" and drag Sellers into the "filter" field

Comment: I can not create a pivot chart because the cell where you choose the seller is also used in other formulas to filter and display other data.